# mongodump command with timestamp query

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, mongodump

When I execute the below query in mongodb shell, it gives me the number of records updated after the mentioned timestamp.

```
db.getCollection('oplog.rs').find({"ts":{"$gt":Timestamp(1582823397,2)}})
```

I wish to execute a similar query with mongodump command. Below is how I'm trying to do it.

```
query.json
{ "ts" : { "$gt" : Timestamp(1582823397,2) } }

mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:27018 -d local -c oplog.rs --queryFile=query.json -o - > D:/MongoDB/Backup/1582823
397_2_oplog.bson
```

The above command doesn't work and throws the below mentioned error.

```
Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input. Position: 19. Character: T
```

Which seems valid as the query.json doesn't follow the JSON rules.

If I change the query.json file as below.

```
query.json
{"ts":{"$gt":"Timestamp(1582823397,2)"}}
```

The query doesn't return any records.

All of the above is a part of a shell script that is supposed to give me incremental dumps.

Reference of the script is taken from [here](https://tech.willhaben.at/mongodb-incremental-backups-dff4c8f54d58). Referred [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107987/mongodb-incremental-backups) as well.

I'm open to any other suggestions of getting incremental backups of MongoDB.

Adding in response to Wernfried's comment.

```
{
    "ts" : Timestamp(1582823446, 1),
    "t" : NumberLong(4),
    "h" : NumberLong(0),
    "v" : 2,
    "op" : "i",
    "ns" : "uis.healthCheck",
    "ui" : UUID("60d2d4de-48a3-46ec-a948-6fcb676ba52f"),
    "wall" : ISODate("2020-02-27T17:10:46.010Z"),
    "o" : {
        "_id" : 2,
        "status" : "Success2"
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to create a oplog dump you may use the `--oplog` option.

Comment: [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format is like this: `{"$timestamp":{"t":1565545664,"i":1}}`

Comment: @RahulParyani, What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan MongoDB version is 4.2.2... Additionally, I have this setup on Windows Server 2012

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have added the way document is stored oplog.rs collection. I have no idea how to apply the suggestion given by you. Once again, I need a query that returns records greater than a specific timestamp from oplog.rs... Thanks

Comment: Use this syntax in the `query.json` file: `{ "ts": { "$gt" : { "$timestamp": { "t": 1582823397,"i": 2 } } } }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by the suggestions given in the comments by @WernfriedDomscheit and @prasad_

Now my mongodump command is as below

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:27018 -d local -c oplog.rs --query "{\"ts\":{\"\$gt\":{\"\$timestamp\":{\"t\":${TIMESTAMP_LAST_OPLOG_ENTRY},\"i\":${INC_NUMBER_LAST_OPLOG_ENTRY}}}}}" -o - > ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${TIMESTAMP_LAST_OPLOG_ENTRY}_${INC_NUMBER_LAST_OPLOG_ENTRY}_oplog.bson 2>> "$LOG_FILE"
```

"TIMESTAMP_LAST_OPLOG_ENTRY" and "INC_NUMBER_LAST_OPLOG_ENTRY" are being fetched from the previous '.bson' file.

Thanks,
Rahul Paryani

Answer (score -2):

--query "{ "startTime":{ "$gte": { "$date": "2020-02-14T04:07:34Z" } } }"