# mongodump failing with invalid json input

Tags: mongodb-3.4, mongodump

**mongodump failing with invalid json input**

```
mongod --version
db version v3.4.1
git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1404
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64


/usr/bin/mongodump -u backup -p backup12345  --host=XX.XX.XX.XX --port XXXX --out=/tmp -d local -c oplog.rs --gzip --authenticationDatabase admin --query "{'ts': { \$gt: Timestamp(1619548593, 1) } }" --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates

2021-04-28T01:21:37.694-0700    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input
```

**anyone can figure what's the issue here ?**

I understand that I'm using 3.4.1 which is older but still it is working on the other server and with same version. The same query runs perfectly alright on a different cluster node.

**Also tried using the latest version of mongodump still the same error.**

mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu1804-x86_64-100.3.1.tgz

---

**I passed the same --query parameter as below in my command and I'm getting corresponding error**

```
--query '{ "ts": { "$gt": Timestamp(1111111, 1) }}'
```

> 2021-04-28T11:10:01.328-0700    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: error decoding key ts: invalid JSON input. Position: 17. Character: T

```
--query '{ "ts": { "$gt": ISODate("2021-04-05T08:00:00.000Z") }}'
```

> 2021-04-28T11:10:35.627-0700    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: error decoding key ts: invalid JSON input. Position: 17. Character: I

```
--query "{ 'ts': { \$gt:  ISODate(\"2021-04-05T08:00:00.000Z\") }}"
```

> 2021-04-28T11:11:20.797-0700    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the input:

```
/usr/bin/mongodump -u backup -p backup12345  --host=XX.XX.XX.XX --port XXXX --out=/tmp -d local -c oplog.rs --gzip --authenticationDatabase admin \
--query '{"ts": { "$gt": Timestamp(1619548593, 1) } }'
--ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates
```

I tried multiple versions and they worked fine with me:

- `--query '{ "ts": { "$gt": Timestamp(1111111, 1) }}'`
- `--query '{ "ts": { "$gt": ISODate("2021-04-05T08:00:00.000Z") }}'`
- `--query "{ 'ts': { \$gt:  ISODate(\"2021-04-05T08:00:00.000Z\") }}"`

In older mongo versions you need to use the "extended json":

- `--query '{ "ts": { "$gt": {"$timestamp":{"t":1565545664,"i":1}} }}'`

this is completetly valid json and should work with the old client as well.

also see [mongodump command with timestamp query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260814/mongodump-command-with-timestamp-query)